# How to get the current website login name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to setup a trigger in SQL Server to log what the users do, like creating new products & etc.

How do I get the current website login username in SQL Server when they create new product in the front end? (Note: Not the username to login to database or the database user login that perform the insert/update/delete, it is the username to login to a website and that username & password are stored in a table).

For example, a front end user login to our website with username Janedoe and password 123456, then she creates a new product called ABC. In the database, this is recognize as an insert to a table called product, so how can I get that username Janedoe using SQL Server?

Comment: You just have to write code as part of your front end to log whatever it is that you want to log. There is nothing you can do automatically.

Comment: Normally if a user is logged in your create an authentication token/cookie. Normally your cookie will store the id or similar or the user who is logged in. You then have to pass that ID to your insert/update SQL statements. There is no automatic way to obtain it from within SQL Server, because it doesn't have any way of knowing that sort of thing.

Comment: In addition to what Dale K has said I'd like to add that a trigger wouldn't be the way to handle logging.  This should be handled in your stored procedures.  At a minimum I would normally have 4 audit columns on all my tables (DateAdded, DateUpdated, AddedUser and UpdatedUser).  In addition it is useful to have a separate audit table recording all actions by users as well as any errors in your procs.